# Passing Custom Binder between packages

Tags: java, android

How do you send a custom Binder object between android packages? say from a service to an activity (in separate packages)?

I've been playing with this for a while but cannot seem to get it to work.

CustomBinder is contained in a library that both packages have a copy of.

The error is at the casting point in onServiceConnected. I always see "Casting Failed".

I've noticed a bit more interesting things to this. When I override the toString method in my CustomBinder, and make it return some string, and I then print out the Binder i get, I get "android.os.BinderProxy" instead.

Updated code to reflect:

Package 1 (Contains the activity)

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection(){
     @Override
     public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder){
          Log.d("TAG",binder.toString());
          try{
               CustomBinder nBinder = (CustomBinder)binder;
               Log.d("TAG","It worked!");
          }catch(Exception e){
               Log.d("TAG","Casting failed again");
          }
     }

     @Override
     public void onServiceDisconnect(ComponentName name){}
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     Intent intent = new Intent();
     intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.testService","com.example.testService.MainService");     
     bindService(intent, mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

Package 2 (Contains the Service)

...

```
@Override
public onBind(Intent intent){
     CustomBinder binder = new CustomBinder();
     return binder;
}
```

CustomBinder in Library

```
// This literally does nothing for now
Public class CustomBinder extends Binder{
     @Override
     public String toString(){
          return "CustomBinder";
     }
}
```

Comment: Please show your non-working code and the problem evidence (error message, etc.).

Comment: Uploaded code snippet and included where the error is occuring

Comment: Just an update, I've found that using it internally (so binding to a service that is inside the same package as the activity), it passes the Casting test I have here.

Any ideas?

Comment: you cannot use "local bound service" pattern when your client and Service are in different processes... see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) for more info

Comment: Reading the bound services part of that link. Would it be possible to send a custom Message with serialized objects (or parcels i believe) to the activity?

Or would i be looking at learning AIDL to do it?